# Name Phone Pad keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, html

What is the input type in html for the NamePhonePad keyboard to appear.

I currently use the input=tel to restrict the keyboard to a numeric only but i would like the option of the ABC to input a letter if needed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

you can use address type of keyboard to enter.number with text.
or you can user regex for specific input format.

may this hint help you.

Comment: Thanks Sunil Thats what i was using alright was just wondering is there a way to get this keyboard http://www.globalnerdy.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/name-phone-pad-2.png